# Can't create table with PostgreSQL including "#" (npgsql.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, npgsql

So I've actually got two issues with **PostgreSQL**. I actually use **npgsql.NET** to create queries, connections, other with PostgreSQL, however I am new to this database software.

## First Issue

I got the error:

```cs
Npgsql.PostgresException: '42601: syntax error at or near "#"

POSITION: 16'
```

after using the script:

```sql
CREATE TABLE {textBox1.Text} (
    user_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR ( 50 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR ( 255 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    created_on TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
        last_login TIMESTAMP
);
```

The `textbox1.Text` included: Pronner#2223.

## Second Issue

When creating a table with the name `PRONNER` for example, it shows up as `pronner`. What's wrong with the capitalization system? Or can it possibly be because I'm using `pgAdmin 4` so I just see it as lower case there?

I'm quite new to this like I mentioned at the beginning of the issue, and I used to use `MySQL` so the syntax is a teensy bit different, but the system is very different.

Comment: Why would you want to use such a special character in a table name? You'd have trouble using such a character in a file name or a URL too. And why does the table have such a weird name? Are you trying to store data in the table name? That's *not* a good idea

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am using Tables for Accounts & Account data instead of inserting into tables that already exist. I find it somehow more efficient, and less annoying. and for the weird name part, "Pronner" is just my username. I used it as a test.

Comment: Eitherway, the issue was solved.

Comment: No, it's not more efficient, quite the opposite. Especially if by `account` you really mean Tenant. PostgreSQL supports [multiple schemas per database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html). You can have a different schema per tenant. In the [connection string](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html) you can set a different schema search path for different tenants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) says

> There is a second kind of identifier: the delimited identifier or
> quoted identifier. It is formed by enclosing an arbitrary sequence of
> characters in double-quotes ("). A delimited identifier is always an
> identifier, never a key word.

So if you want to use uppercase and any special character, you must (always) double quote the name:

```
create table "TE#st" (id integer);
select * from "TE#st";
```

Answer (score 0):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) the `#` sign is not allowed in a SQL identifier:

> SQL identifiers and key words must begin with a letter (a-z, but also letters with diacritical marks and non-Latin letters) or an underscore (_). Subsequent characters in an identifier or key word can be letters, underscores, digits (0-9), or dollar signs ($). Note that dollar signs are not allowed in identifiers according to the letter of the SQL standard,

The lower case names are also documented in the chapter:

> Quoting an identifier also makes it case-sensitive, whereas unquoted names are always folded to lower case. For example, the identifiers FOO, foo, and "foo" are considered the same by PostgreSQL, but "Foo" and "FOO" are different from these three and each other. (The folding of unquoted names to lower case in PostgreSQL is incompatible with the SQL standard, which says that unquoted names should be folded to upper case. Thus, foo should be equivalent to "FOO" not "foo" according to the standard. If you want to write portable applications you are advised to always quote a particular name or never quote it.)

Comment: so basically "#" is just not allowed? And for lower case, does it actually differ from higher case when trying to `SELECT`? Is it case-sensitive or not? Let's say someone is trying to login with the username `Pronner`, but he registered it as `PRONNER`, would it work? And is there any other way to make # still work or not?

Comment: The value in a column is something completely different than the name of a table.

Comment: When did I ever mention a column? I'm talking about Table values.

Comment: @Pronner: in your question: "*When creating a table with the name PRONNER for example*"

Comment: So basically it's the same table name that I wrote, but it doesn't appear the same on the table when using pgAdmin 4?